# IDL - calculate mean ignoring zeros

Tags: array, function, idl

Imagine the following array:

```
a = [10768,10764,10893,10763,10723,10792,0,0,0,0]
```

Using a function like "MEAN" in IDL, is there a way to calculate the mean value, ignoring the zeros? I know this can easily be done in a for-loop, but I would prefer a ready made function for the sake of simplicity and performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always make a [selection](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/WHERE.html) of the [valid](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/Relational_Operators.html) items:

```
a[WHERE(a NE 0)]
```